# Trailing characters in URL after Facebook Login

Tags: java, facebook, redirect, facebook-authentication

I am going through the facebook authentication process to log my users into my site.  Once a user is logged in I redirect to the profile page using:

```
resp.sendRedirect("/l/profile");
```

But when I get to the profile page, the URL ends `/profile#_=_`

This seems to be at the end of the URL redirected by facebook when it returns a code.  Why is it sticking around, how do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it's a byproduct of new feature called "Authenticated Referrals" whereby they add a valid accessToken to the end of the url as either an #anchor or ?param (depending on whether you're reading it client- or server-side). You can read more about it here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication/

At any rate, because it's appended Facebook-side, you'll have to [file a bug](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs) with them to fix it, although at the moment the tracker seems to be down for me.

Comment: Is there any way to strip it from my url, I am redirecting from the login page to the profile page.  Why does resp.sendRedirect("/l/profile") keep the garbage?

Comment: I didn't realise you were using Java, I had assumed the redirect was from Facebook to your server. The problem appears to be within the `resp` object, and I'm not sure why it's adding an anchor, although it looks like it's a result of some key => value from somewhere. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.